# Error al iniciar Cisco Packet Tracer en Debian: libQt5NetworkAuth.so.5: cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, debian

He instalado Cisco Packet Tracer en Debian 10, especificamente deepin 20. Lo instale del siguiente link: https://www.netacad.com/portal/resources/packet-tracer, seleccionando la opción: "Ubuntu Desktop Version 8.0.1 English 64 Bit Download", se que la opción es para Ubuntu, pero pensé que funcionaria porque se instaló un paquete '.deb': "CiscoPacketTracer_801_Ubuntu_64bit.deb". Instale las dependencias, y luego ejecute: `apt install ./CiscoPacketTracer_801_Ubuntu_64bit.deb`.

Se terminó de instalar y ya lo encontré en el menú de aplicaciones
[image: Se terminó de instalar y ya lo encontré en el menú de aplicaciones]

Intente abrir la aplicación, pero solo cargo un momentó y no abrió nada. Decidí abrirlo desde la terminal para ver si mandaba un error:
[image: Intente abrir la aplicación, pero solo cargo un momentó y no abrió nada. Decidí abrirlo desde la terminal para ver si mandaba un error:]

Entonces busqué el archivo "libQt5NetworkAuth.so.5", y lo encontré en la carpeta "/opt/pt/bin". Decidí agregar esa carpeta a la variable PATH, y no funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

Si es una librería, el `PATH` no afecta. Tendrías que modificar la variable de entorno `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`... por ejemplo

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pt/bin
./llamar-al-ejecutable-de-la-aplicacion
```

Lo otro que podrías intentar es instalar el paquete de debian que lo tiene:

```
$ apt-file search libQt5NetworkAuth.so.5
libqt5networkauth5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5NetworkAuth.so.5
libqt5networkauth5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5NetworkAuth.so.5.15
libqt5networkauth5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5NetworkAuth.so.5.15.2
```

Eso es en `debian testing` por si acaso.

Así que instalando el paquete `libqt5networkauth5` también debería funcionar (aunque puede ser que la aplicación necesite *específicamente* el que viene con el).

Comment: Gracias. El error desapareció despues de instalar libqt5networkauth5 y libqt5networkauth5-dev, pero ahora aparecen otros 2: ```/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by ./PacketTracer)```  y  ```/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./PacketTracer)```

Comment: Ya eso me suena a no tener la versión de glibc para la que fue compilada la aplicación. Estas usando una distro/versión soportada?

Comment: No, uso Deepin, y la instalación solo estaba disponible para Ubuntu. Imaginé que funcionaría porque ambas distribuciones son derivadas de Debian. Trataré de usarlo en una maquina virtual con Windows.